# how to get the load average of a container inside it which is based on cgroup such as docker?

Tags: docker, load, uptime

How to get the load average of a container inside it which is based on cgroup such as docker?

The command line `uptime` and `top` show the load average of the container host.

Comment: Not sure I know what you are asking. Do you mean something like Docker stats? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/

Comment: docker stats can get some data outside the container, but I want to get these data inside a container.

Comment: Still use Docker stats just mount it inside the container and run it from there.
https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/69axu7/how_to_run_docker_stats_inside_a_docker_container/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `docker stats` could be used inside a container. but `docker stats` does not contain the status value I am seeking for.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_(computing)